# no selector "plus" for type "POLINOMIO" why?

Tags: ada

This is the code about,polynomials_test.adb calls function plus of polynomial.ads. BUT is not compiling yet send message: not selector plus for type POLINOMIO.

Why and how to resolved it? Thx.

--------------polynomial.ads--------------------

```
 --function plus
   --return c = a + b
    function plus( Poly1, Poly2: Polynomial ) return Polynomial is
        Poly_Sum : Polynomial := Zero_Polynomial;
   begin
        Poly_Sum.High_Power := Max( Poly1.High_Power, Poly2.High_Power );
        if Poly_Sum.High_Power > Max_Degree then
            raise Polynomial_Error;
        end if;
        for i in 0..Poly_Sum.High_Power loop
            Poly_Sum.Coeff_Array( i ) := Poly1.Coeff_Array( i ) + Poly2.Coeff_Array( i );
        end loop;

        return Poly_Sum;
   end plus;


-------------polynomials_test.adb----------------------
--libraries
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

--package
with Polynomials; use Polynomials;

--main
procedure Polynomials_Test is

   --coef and deg
 type POLINOMIO is
      record
         coef    : INTEGER; -- this an array
         deg     : INTEGER;
      end record;


   poli_a : polinomial := (others => 1 );

   type ACCESS_MY_DATA is access POLINOMIO;

   --Unchecked_Deallocation: delete an object from the heap
   procedure Free is new
                Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(POLINOMIO, ACCESS_MY_DATA);

    --definitions
     &   : ACCESS_MY_DATA;
   Zero  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(0,0);
     p1  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(4,3);
     p2  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(3,2);
     p3  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(1,0);
     p4  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(2,1);
     p   : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(4,3);
     q1  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(3,2);
     q2  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(1,0);
     q   : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(2,1);
     r   : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(3,2);
     s   : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(1,0);
     t   : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(2,1);
     p5  : ACCESS_MY_DATA := new POLINOMIO'(0,1);

     pa : Poly := new Polynomial;
     pb : Poly := new Polynomial;

begin

   --asignation and initialization
    & := new POLINOMIO;
   Zero := new POLINOMIO;
   p1 := new POLINOMIO;
   p2 := new POLINOMIO;
   p3 := new POLINOMIO;
   p4 := new POLINOMIO;
   p  := new POLINOMIO;

   p5 := new POLINOMIO;

   q1 := new POLINOMIO;
   q2 := new POLINOMIO;
   q  := new POLINOMIO;

   r := new POLINOMIO;
   s := new POLINOMIO;
   t := new POLINOMIO;


   --polynomial  functions
   Zero := new POLINOMIO'(0,0);
   p1 := new POLINOMIO'(4,3);
   p2 := new POLINOMIO'(3,2);
   p3 := new POLINOMIO'(1,0);
   p4 := new POLINOMIO'(2,1);
   p  := new POLINOMIO'(4,3);
   p := p1 & p2 & p3 & p4;

   --p:= p1.plus_2(p2).plus_2(p3).plus_2(p4);

   q1 := new POLINOMIO'(3,2);
   q2 := new POLINOMIO'(5,0);
   q := q1.plus(q2);

   --q  := q1.plus(q2);

   Put_Line("Polynoms:");
   put("zero(x) =   " & Integer'Image(p3.deg));
   New_Line;
   -- p(x) =        4x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1
   put("p(x) =      " & Integer'Image(p));

end Polynomials_Test;
```

Comment: Please reduce your example code to a minimal example which shows the problem you have.

Comment: In the example above also send this msn: there is no applicable "&" for type "ACCESS_MY_DATA" defined at line 21.

Comment: You have removed the definition of type `Polynomials.Polynomial` - which is what your function `Polynomials.plus` handles - from the question. For some reason, you’ve defined *another* type `Polynomials_Test.POLINOMIO`, and you’re expecting `Polynomials.plus` to handle it. **ADA DOES NOT WORK LIKE THIS**; types declared in different places are not substitutable, even if they have the same structure, which yours do not. In `POLINOMIO`, saying `coef  : INTEGER; -- this an array` doesn’t magically make it an array. For a start, get rid of `POLINOMIO` and use `Polynomials.Polynomial` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

These subprograms (functions and procedures) are probably not what you want them to be: they are declared within the `Polynomials` package, but do not reference the type `Polynomial` at all.

Apart from that, your question is easily answered: `POLYNOMIO` is not a tagged type, so object.function notation does not work. You should call type.function instead, i.e. `Polynomials.times (q)`.

I would guess that you are using experience (or some pre-written code) from a language like C++ or Java. There, the functions (methods) belong to the class/type and take an implicit parameter to an instance of that class. This is not the case in Ada: the functions belong to the *package*, and you have to add a parameter yourself, e.g.

```
function times (p: Polynomial; b: Integer) return Integer;
```

(Shouldn't it return a Polynomial?)

A question: why do you declare two similar types, `Polynomials.Polynomial` and `Polynomials_Test.POLYNOMIO`?

Comment: @Tania: Unlike Java, Ada supports operator overloading, and operator `&` is used for string concatenation, so: `p := p1 & p2 & p3 & p4;`

Comment: How write in Ada this symbol: + ? i have a string like this one: p(x)      =  4x** 3 3x** 2 2x** 1 1x** 0 but there should be some symbols "+".Thx.